Estimating an upper bound of hyperbolicity constants in Gromov-hyperbolic groups
Is there any good references with an explicit estimating  hyperbolicity constants of hyperbolic groups? I was thinking about whether there is any relation between the relator of maximal length in the hyperbolic group with a hyperbolicity constant so that, one can approximate  the hyperbolicity constant by the length of the maximal relator in a group?

From an algorithmic point of view, there is this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9811012, but it’s not quite as explicit as what you were asking for.

There is no computable upper bound on the hyperbolicity constant of hyperbolic groups in terms of maximal relator length. Hyperbolicity is not a decidable property of finitely presented groups by the Adian-Rabin theorem, but it is partially decidable [1]. That algorithm won't terminate on non-hyperbolic groups, but if you could give it an upper bound on the hyperbolicity constant then it would terminate having verified non-hyperbolicity, contradicting undecidability.
[1] Papasoglu, P., An algorithm detecting hyperbolicity, Baumslag, Gilbert (ed.) et al., Geometric and computational perspectives on infinite groups. Proceedings of a joint DIMACS/Geometry Center workshop, January 3-14, 1994 at the University of Minnesota, Minneapolis, MN, USA and March 17-20, 1994 at DIMACS, Princeton, NJ, USA. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society. DIMACS, Ser. Discrete Math. Theor. Comput. Sci. 25, 193-200 (1996). ZBL0857.20017..
